# Remove pink validation background from DataGrid

Tags: c#, silverlight, datagrid

When one of my datagrid rows is invalid, the datagrid shows a validation summary at the bottom of the DataGrid and additionally makes the background pink for the invalid row.

In my application, both shouldnt happen. I already had success removing the ValidationSummary by getting the summary template child and setting its height to zero:

```
base.OnApplyTemplate();
var summaryCtrl = GetTemplateChild("ValidationSummary");
((ValidationSummary)summaryCtrl).MaxHeight = 0;
```

However, I am stuck with the pink background. Is there an easy way to remove it?

Answer (score 0):

You can customise the `DataGrid` by giving it a custom template. The fact it is pink sounds like you're already using a custom template, but irrespective of that if you

- Right-click the `DataGrid` in xaml view
- `Edit Template > Edit a copy`
- Choose a name and location for this template

You can then inspect the template it is using and make modifications to the `ValidationSummary` and any other elements that change colour (for example) when in a state of validation error.